# How do you allow an object to use fields stored in another object?

Tags: java

Say you create a class called Album and a class called Song. You want Album objects to be able to use the fields stored within Song objects (for example, the song's filesize or runtime). What do you have to do to allow this to happen?

I've tried changing my fields within Song to public instead of private, but that hasn't worked. To be honest, I'm new to OOP and I think I'm overlooking something pretty fundamental here.

Comment: can you post your `Album` and `Song` classes?  it's a bit easier to show you what's going on with actual code.

Comment: Inheritance could work like you want in this situation.

Comment: @Frunk It would help if you said a bit more about this. Clearly we wouldn't want Song to inherit from Album (since a Song isn't a type of Album) so what do you mean here?

Answer (score 1):

fields has to be private
that s why you can create accessors
getters and setters

see example :

```
Adding Setter and Getter Methods
```

To make the state of the managed bean accessible, you need to add setter and getter methods for that state. 
Once the setter and getter methods have been added, the bean is complete. The final code looks like this:

```
public class Printer {


    private String name;


    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:

1. Make the fields in question public. Not recommended, since it violates encapsulation
2. Provide "getter" methods in Song to return the values in question. The usual answer, sometimes also the correct one
3. Provide a method in Song to return a String representing the information you want. Useful if there's a complex of information that Song should be responsible for representing.

Generally speaking, I prefer to let objects "tend to their own knitting" as much as possible. To this end, I would always try to handle data in the class that owns it if it makes sense to do so. In this case, it makes sense for Album to compose the Song data into some presentable form, so I would suggest using getters in your song class to provide access, for example:

```
public int getFileSize(){
  return fileSize;
}

public String getName(){
  return name;
}
```

Then Album can put those together however it likes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an Album would contain a list of songs.

For example :

```
public class Album 
{
    private List <Song> songs;

    public Album ()
    {
        songs = new ArrayList <Song>();
    }
}
```

Song would have public methods such as `getName()` and `getLength()`, which would allow an `Album` object to access them.

For example :

```
public int totalLength ()
{
    int length = 0;
    for (Song song : songs)
         length += song.getLength();
    return length;
}
```